# error en depencias de build.gradle (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo un error no me aparece la libreria 19.0.1 para agregar a dependencias de build.gradle.
Cual puede ser el error?adjunto imagenes del proyecto.
[[image]build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaeM7.png)

[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]librerias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZRyJ.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Elenasys hola elena, disculpa que te moleste pero quiero compilar para que la app funcione en 4.4.2  y me salta error en el archivo v21.styles

Comment: Acabo de ver tu error, son dos cosas importantes primero asegurar tener instalado el SDK 21 y cambiar targetSdkVersion 21 agrego respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener definido tu [targetSDK](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) como API 21, por supuesto debes instalar el SDK.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    ...
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...
    }
}
```

Asegura tener instalado el SDK API 21

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer está mal tu referencia. Escribe `buildToolsVersion "19.1"` sin ".0".

Comment: Hola amigo Dan, de Build Tools si existe una versión 19.1.0 (May 2014)  https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html